# Linux Shell - String manipulation then calculating age of file in minutes

Tags: linux, string, shell, time

I am writing a script that calculates the age of the oldest file in a directory. The first commands run are:

```
OLDFILE=`ls -lt $DIR | grep "^-" | tail -1 `    
echo $OLDFILE
```

The output contains a lot more than just the filename. eg

```
-rwxrwxr-- 1 abc abc 334 May 10 2011 ABCD_xyz20110510113817046.abc.bak
```

Q1/. How do I obtain the output after the last space of the above line? This would give me the filename. I realise some sort of string manipulation is required but am new to shell scripting.

Q2/. How do I obtain the age of this file in minutes?

Comment: what do you mean by `How do I obtain the age of this file in minutes`?

Comment: To add to the comment by @Bill - on most Unix/Linux file systems, the time that a file was created is not stored. So you can find either the last time that the data of a file was changed (its `mtime`) or the last time metadata about the file (permissions, size, owner, etc.) was changed (its `ctime`), and sometimes, the last time the file was read (its `atime`) - although `atime` is often either completely disabled, or only approximated, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain just the oldest file's name,

```
ls -lt | awk '/^-/{file=$NF}END{print file}'
```

However, this is not robust if you have files with spaces in their names, etc. Generally, you should try to [avoid parsing the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

With `stat` you can obtain a file's creation date in machine-readable format, expressed as seconds since Jan 1, 1970; with `date +%s` you can obtain the current time in the same format. Subtract and divide by 60. (More Awk skills would come in handy for the arithmetic.)

Finally, for an alternate solution, look at the options for `find`; in particular, its `printf` format strings allow you to extract a file's age. The following will directly get you the age in seconds and inode number of the oldest file:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %i\n' |
sort -n | head -n 1
```

Using the inode number avoids the issues of funny file names; once you have a single inode, converting that to a file name is a snap:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -inum "$number"
```

Tying the two together, you might want something like this:

```
# set -- Replace $@ with output from command
set -- $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %i\n' |
         sort -n | head -n 1)
# now $1 is the timestamp and $2 is the inode

oldest_filename=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -inum "$2")
age_in_minutes=$(date +%s | awk -v d="$1" '{ print ($1 - d) / 60 }')
```

Comment: Running `find` twice might suck on a large directory.

Comment: `ls -lt` will prefer the alphabetically last file if there are multiple oldest files with the same date stamp, while `sort` will tend to prefer the lowest (oldest?) inode number, so they are not precisely equivalent, and hard to make so.

Comment: Also `find` will include dot files while `ls` will not.  You can add `-name '[!.]*'` to fix that.

Comment: Note that (Li|U)nix `ctime` is not creation time. It stands for "change time" and indicates the last time something about the inode itself (permissions, etc.) was changed, not when the inode was first allocated to that file. Some file systems may store a creation time, but most don't.

Comment: I was aiming for the modification time but I got distracted and put the wrong format code. Thanks for the comment; updated answer.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the reply. Apologies for the delay, I was expecting an email to advise of replies but didn't work!

Comment: @tripleee The ls command worked perfectly to obtain the filename of the oldest file. However it seems that the find command is better suited, there aren't many files in the directory either - so this solution is suitable.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: @tripleee the age in minutes of the oldest file also worked.
One thing I don't get - when running the command 
'find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %i\n' |
         sort -n | head -n 1'
The first result is always the same number. Shouldn't it increase over time?

Comment: No, the numbers at that stage are the inode number and the file's modification time. The age is obtained by subtracting the mtime from the current time.

Answer (score 0):

an `awk` solution, giving you how old the file is in minutes, (as your ls output does not contain the min of creation, so 00 is assumed by default). Also as tripleee pointed out, `ls` outputs are inherently risky to be parsed.

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$ echo $l; echo "##############";echo $l | awk -f test.sh ; echo "#############"; cat test.sh
-rwxrwxr-- 1 abc abc 334 May 20 2013 ABCD_xyz20110510113817046.abc.bak
##############
File ABCD_xyz20110510113817046.abc.bak is 2074.67 min old
#############
BEGIN{
   m=split("Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec",d,"|")
   for(o=1;o<=m;o++){
      date[d[o]]=sprintf("%02d",o)
    }
}
{
month=date[$6];
old_time=mktime($8" "month" "$7" "00" "00" "00);
curr_time=systime();
print "File " $NF " is " (curr_time-old_time)/60 " min old";
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this is an exercise or awk homework? I can't think of a practical use of parsing `ls` data  to find out age of the file

Answer (score 0):

For Q2 a bash one-liner could be:

```
let mtime_minutes=\(`date +%s`-`stat -c%Y "$file_to_inspect"`\)/60
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `ls -t`. Including the '-l' option explicitly asks for ls to give you all that other info that you actually want to get rid of.
However what you probably REALLY want is find, first:

```
NEWEST=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | cut -c3- |xargs ls -t| head -1)
```

this will get you the plain filename of the newest item, no other processing needed.
Directories will be correctly excluded. (thanks to tripleee for pointing out that's what you were aiming for.)

For the second question, you can use stat and bc:

```
TIME_MINUTES=$(stat --format %Y/60 "$NEWEST" |bc -l)
```

remove the '-l' option from bc if you only want a whole number of minutes.

Comment: This will still break for file names with newlines, but I grant you that's a marginal scenario.

Comment: I suppose you could avoid the inelegant `echo` with `stat --format '%Y/60'`?

Comment: @triplee: yeah, filenames containing special characters are too hard, as far as I'm concerned. Otherwise I'd spend another step escaping any double quotes and $. There's a limit to the patience I have with bash's halfbaked quoting. Thanks for the suggestion, I've edited it in.